# Is Context Switch a O(1) process

Tags: operating-system

Is context switch a O(1) process or the context switch quantum is dependent on various local factors that can affect the time taken for it?

Comment: Which operating system, and which method are you asking about?

Comment: I have read that PCBs((Process Control Block s) ) are arranged in linked list fashion so to load a particular PCB one needs to find that PCB which will be O(n) so I think context switch is going to be of order O(n). Does this vary from OS to OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for many different reasons. The main one being that switching context between two threads of a same process, and switching context between two threads of different process imply an **address-space** change. Changing the address-space is always a costly operation for the caches and memory. On x86 you will need to reload the *Page Directory*, on PowperPC you will need to invalidate and reload the *TLB*, ...

*Changing address-space is not mandatory when going from a thread to the kernel. Just to remaind, I think Linux has always the kernel address-space loaded (using the PAE facility and having an entry of the 4-entry PDBR locked with the kernel address-space, starting at the AS higher halves, at 0xc0000000).*